# BGE - Stop ApplyRotation

Tags: python, game-engine

I'm using 'ApplyRotation' but the object does not stop spinning.

```
import bge
from bge import logic

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
owner = cont.owner

for i in ranger(0, 100)
    owner.applyRotation([0,.02, 0], 1)
```

Comment: What sensor to you have running the script? It will run every time the sensor triggers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

applyRotation is (like most operations in Python) a one time operation.

It applies the provided turn exactly once at the moment of calling.

When you discover a continuous turning it means you execute this operation multiple time.

When you can see the turning (=animation) you do apply the turns at different frames resulting in a turning animation (one frame = one step).

Your code applies a lot of small turns (steps) in one frame. This means you will only see the final orientation. As there should not be a problem in calculating this final operation your code is very inefficient and is wasting processing time.

Keep in mind:

- Your code describes the behavior within a **single frame**.

To get the animated turning you execute the code at each frame when you want a turn step.

> I'm using 'ApplyRotation' but the object does not stop spinning.

This sounds like you execute the code at each single frame (see sensor settings).